# Powershell - New-Object System.IO.StreamReader

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a code to make my daily life easier :)

The code below works if I indicate the file path

```
$ stream_reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader {c:\test.txt}
```

However it does not work when I use a variable like:

```
$ stream_reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader {$FileIOC}
```

**How to use it:**

1. Create a file text containing md5 entries
2. Run the script and specify the file.
3. Normally, a file name like : "randomID.ioc" will be created

**Code**

```
  try {
      $FileIOC = read-host "Where is located the text file containing iOC"
      if (Test-Path $FileIOC) {
      write-host "File found at:" $FileIOC
      
      } else {
      write-host "Unable to file iOC file into: " $FileIOC
             }
         } 
    catch { 
        #Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        #Write-Host "Unable to find $hotfix"
        }


try {
    # GUI ID Generation
    $GUID = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    #[guid]::NewGuid()
    Write-Host "Generating ID: " $GUID
    }
    catch { 
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }

# Variables
$gdate = Get-Date -format s
$Hostname = "$GUID.ioc"

# Where I am
$Locate = Get-Location
$Folder = "$Locate\"
#write-host "Path :" $Folder

# Create file format GUID.ioc (# create xml)
# `n <== Enter
   New-Item -path $Folder -name $Hostname -type "file" -value "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" 
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "`n<ioc xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" id=""$GUID"" last-modified=""$gdate"" xmlns=""http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc"">"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <short_description>Custom EDR-O iOC</short_description>"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <short_description>Custom EDR-O iOC $Hostname $gdate</short_description>"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <keywords />"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <authored_by>LEFBE</authored_by>"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <authored_date>$gdate</authored_date>"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <links />"
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  <definition>"
   
   # For each line in text files
   # Generate ID
   $GUID1 = [guid]::NewGuid()
   Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "    <Indicator operator=""OR"" id=""$GUID1"">"
   $stream_reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader{"$FileIOC"} #< Here a problem variable was note read by $stream_reader
   while (($current_line =$stream_reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
    {
    Write-Host "$current_line"
    $line_number++
         $GUID2 = [guid]::NewGuid()
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "      <IndicatorItem id=""$GUID2"" condition=""is"">"
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "        <Context document=""FileItem"" search=""FileItem/Md5sum"" type=""mir"" />"
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "        <Content type=""md5"">$current_line</Content>"
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "      </IndicatorItem>"
     }         
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "    </Indicator>"
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "  </definition>"     
         Add-Content -path $Folder$Hostname -value "</ioc>" 


Write-Host ""
Write-Host "iOC file can be found at this location:" "$Folder$Hostname"
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The correct syntax is: `New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $path` or even better: `[System.IO.StreamReader]::new($path)`

Comment: Hello @iRon, 

With your solution I got the same error: 
ERROR: Exception when calling ".ctor" with "1" argument (s): "Illegal characters in path. "
ERROR: Cannot call a method in a null expression.

Using a file path and not the variable works

Comment: That is probably because you didn't close (and dispose) streamreader with previous attempts. Does this answer your question? [Powershell StreamReader - how to wait for a new file to be readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736045/powershell-streamreader-how-to-wait-for-a-new-file-to-be-readable)

Comment: Thanks @iRon after adding $stream_reader.Close() and $stream_reader.Dispose() it works :) ! 


Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iRon for his help.

Solution is :

```
$stream_reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($FileIOC)
# Do some stuff

# Do not forget to close the file and dispose
$stream_reader.Close()
$stream_reader.Dispose()
```